# Prove that the limit of $2^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Prove that the limit of $2^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}}=1$.

I need to show that for each $\epsilon$ there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ \forall n \geq n_0: |2^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}}-1|\lt \epsilon$

I was simply trying to solve $2^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}}=1$ by taking logs, by that doesn't lead my anywhere. Can anybody help please?

Comment: I assume this is an assignment for a class or similar.  Do you have tools available to you?  You might find it more convenient to use that $2^x$ is continuous and work with the (obvious or $\epsilon/\delta$ depending on what you consider acceptable) limit of the exponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't good way, because from $2^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}}=1$ you get $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}=0$-it's not possible.

What you can do:

1) If you know that for all $a>0$ $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ you can use this.

2)If you don't know that for all $a>0$ $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ you can prove this (there is, for example, proof using [Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf{Hint}$: Prove that the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}=0$. This should not be difficult seeing that you understand $\epsilon$-notation.

Answer (score 1):

Surely this works (first year undergrad here - please be gentle!)

$ 2^\frac{-1}{\sqrt n} -1 <\epsilon$

$ 2^\frac{-1}{\sqrt n} <\epsilon +1$

$ \log{2^\frac{-1}{\sqrt n}}<\log(\epsilon +1)$

$ \frac{\log 2}{\sqrt n} >-\log(\epsilon +1)  $

$ \frac{\sqrt n}{\log 2} < \frac{1}{\log(\epsilon +1)}  $

$ \sqrt n < \frac{\log 2}{\log(\epsilon +1)} $

$ n < \log(2-(\epsilon +1))^2 $

So that if you choose N $ \in N $ to be $\lceil \log(2-(\epsilon +1))^2 \rceil$ then $ \forall n >$N,  $|2^\frac{-1}{\sqrt n} -1| <\epsilon$.

Comment: A nice attempt, but note that $2^{-1/\sqrt n}$ is always less than $1$, so your very first inequality has a negative number on the left (and presumably a positive $\epsilon$ on the right).  This is also clear in the fourth inequality, since $\log(x)\gt0$ whenever $x\gt1$.  Where things go off the rails is in the next line:  you can't just drop the minus sign and invert the inequality.

Comment: Oh, there's another problem at the very end:  the division rule for logarithms is $\log(a/b)=\log a-\log b$, not $\log a/\log b=\log(a-b)$.

Comment: ... what is the latex expression for a sad face? Thanks for the steer Barry, I can see where it went wrong. Something to spend a bit more time on methinks!

Comment: Glad to help.  I think if you start from $1-2^{-1/\sqrt n}\lt\epsilon$ (and assume $\epsilon\lt1$), you'll get a nice result.  I'll delete all my comments if you render them irrelevant by editing your answer.  (There's no need to leave clutter in the comments.)